# What is UWP analog for Application.StartupPath?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-mobile

This is my first experience with UWP and currently I porting my WinForms C# app to UWP, so I can use it on my phone.
My app using two files that I store near with it's exe: the PNG and text file. I accessed these with use of `Application.StartupPath + "\\my.png"` and etc. How I can do the same in UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, "/Assets/image.jpg"));
```

Assets is a folder name in your UWP project.

For more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965322.aspx

Comment: So it can be even without `assets` folder?

Answer (score 0):

you cant write files in the application package folder (path where the appx is deployed). You can use ApplicationData class to storage files.

Comment: But how I supposed to put there my files initially? P.S. -1 is not from me.

Comment: sorry the files that come with the app you mean? You can do two things. one use URI like ms-appx:///Assets/image.png or if its not in the image folder use ms-appx:///Image.png. Other solution is via Package.Current.installedLocation

Comment: Yes, my app needs two files to work and I usually put these together with my EXE.